# Excluding pytest files/marks from pre-commit hooks

Tags: python, git, pytest, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

Is there a way to exclude pytests marked with `pytest.mark` from running during the pre-commit hook?
Especially, I'd like to exclude the tests that are marked as integration tests.

The content of a tests looks like this

```py
pytestmark = [pytest.mark.integration, pytest.mark.reporting_api]

### some tests
```

and the `.pre-commit-conifg.yaml` `pytest` configuration is

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pytest
        name: pytest
        entry: pytest test/
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        types: [python]
        stages: [commit, push]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `pre-commit-config.yaml` syntax, but can't you just add the respective command line parameters here? E.g. something like `pytest -m "not integration" test/`?

Comment: It is `pytest -m "not integration"` to exclude the `integration`  pytestmark or `pytest  -k "not integration"` to exclude all files names containing `"integration"`.

Comment: True - and I understand you need the first one. Was that a question?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. How would I add the command line argument shown above to the pre-commit `.yaml` file?

Comment: As I wrote, I'm not familiar with the syntax - I thought you could add it to the `entry` section, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. `entry: pytest -m "not integration" test/` excludes the `integration` pymark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2c: it's not a good idea to run tests as part of `pre-commit` -- in my experience they're going to be too slow and your contributors may get frustrated and turn off the framework entirely

that said, it should be as simple as adding the arguments you want to either `entry` or `args` -- personally I prefer `entry` when working with `repo: local` hooks (since there's nothing that would "conventionally" override `args`)

in your case this would look like:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: pytest
        name: pytest
        entry: pytest test/ -m 'not integration and not reporting_api'
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        types: [python]
        stages: [commit, push]
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit and I'm a pytest core dev

Comment: Very very interesting indication. Thanks a lot. May I ask in your workflow when is it best that you perform your unit tests if not with pre-commit (as you say above)?